# How to nmap without rDNS and write the DNS in the output

Tags: networking, nmap, port-scanning

I need to use nmap to check if port 443 is open for a list websites. So, I saved them into  a file. I need the output to tell me if the port is open or not. I used the command:

```
nmap -PN -p443 gnmap -oG logs/output.gnmap -iL myfolder/input.txt
```

The problem: the output file is giving me a different domain names. Nmap made rDNS and I found that the IP points to adifferent domain name. Please, explain. Does this means both domains are hosted in the same server ? However, I checked their certificates and found each domain has different certificate. I am concerned about port 433 in my list to check their certificates later. So, I don't want to check another domain's certificate's other than the one I entered in the file.

To solve the issue, I used the `-n` option. But the problem is that the output file contains IPs only. How can I produce output file that contains the result of my domains without rDNS ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Grepable" output format (`-oG`) is deprecated because it cannot show the full output of an Nmap scan. There is no way to get the output you want with the `-oG` option unless you modify Nmap and recompile it.

Luckily, the XML output format (`-oX`) contains the information you want and more:

```
<hostnames>
  <hostname name="bonsaiviking.com" type="user"/>
  <hostname name="li34-105.members.linode.com" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
```

In this example, from scanning my domain, the hostname provided on the command line has the attribute `type="user"`, and the hostname that was a result of the reverse lookup has `type="PTR"`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any explanation of what is the domain name with "PTR" ? Is it the server or what ?

Comment: It's a [reverse lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Reverse_lookup). A host may serve multiple virtual hosts (website domains), but it will only have one reverse name.